# Permission deined when attempting to copy file with ugo read permissions

Tags: linux, permission-denied, ext4

The motivation for this question is that I am *no longer* able to create a functioning chroot with debootstrap on my Red Hat machine. About a year, and many Red Hat updates ago I was able to.

```
sudo debootstrap --arch amd64 trusty trusty http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
sudo chroot trusty
```

results in:

```
groups: cannot find name for group ID 0
groups: cannot find name for group ID 1027
I have no name!@wsdev66:/#
```

which is unexpected behavior, as well as a non-functional chroot. Expected output is root@wsdev66:/#. Google has lead me to believe that running /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage would resolve this, but no script or binary with that name exists there. There is a log file named debootstrap.log with the contents:

```
gzip: /usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz: Permission denied
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

which appears to be the source of the failed chroot.

ls indicates read permissions for all:

```
ll /usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3518 Apr  6 09:33 /usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz
```

Checking for ACLs even though there shouldn't be any, judging from the results of the previous command:

```
getfacl /usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

All parent directories are owned by root:root, and have permissions: drwxr-xr-x.

```
cp /usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz ~
cp: cannot open `/usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz' for reading: Permission denied
```

which I believe is incorrect/unexpected. **Why can I not copy this file or successfully create a chroot?**

System information:

> Linux *hostname* 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 3 13:32:45 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> LSB Version:  :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
>
> Distributor ID:   RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
>
> Description:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.5 (Santiago)
>
> Release:  6.5
>
> Codename: Santiago
>
> mount:
>
> > /dev/mapper/vg_ngdw-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming/code questions. Not general Linux usage. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

McAfee VSE for linux 1.9 is not officially supported for RHEL 6.5.

dmesg shows:

```
linuxshield module is older than RHEL 6.2 ... applying fixups
```

The McAfee 'linuxshield' kernel module is causing this issue. Curiously, it cannot be unloaded with modprobe, because attempting to do so results in modprobe being unable to find the 'linuxshield' module, despite that exact name existing in lsmod output. Removing it by stopping the 'nails' service fixes the problem.

This problem can also be fixed by manually running khm_setup -c to recompile the kernel modules.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue with this by stopping all McAfee services:

```
sudo /opt/isec/ens/threatprevention/bin/isectpdControl.sh stop
sudo /opt/isec/ens/esp/bin/isecespdControl.sh stop
```

Ref:  https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB88223